# How to implement Generics DAO with Spring JDBC template

Tags: spring, generics, jdbctemplate

I know how to perform CRUD operation using named JDBC Template of Spring. But I'm trying to figure out how to make CRUD operation generic. If anyone have idea, please post some example or sample codes.

Answer (score 2):

you can use generic `CrudRepository` from spring-data. or write something simillar: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251166/The-Generic-DAO-pattern-in-Java-with-Spring-3-and

Comment: That article is for JPA, not JDBC Template